# How to work directly on the server with PhpStorm?

Tags: drupal, server, configuration, phpstorm, web-deployment

It is possible to work directly on a remote server, without download the files local with PhpStorm?

Comment: check out https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-host-tool-window.html this is how u can do it

Comment: Well ... you can use "Edit Remote File" action from Remote Host tool window (it will download file in background) .. but it will have limited functionality (if IDE cannot index your code then it cannot provide help with completion for those classes/functions). I strongly suggest to have local copy and upload changes when needed ("local code first, remote is just a copy")

Comment: @LazyOne this is the way I work in my university as a student! But now I just started working as a junior developer on a company and they have a different workflow. They develop directly on the production server and it's very difficult for me because of phpstorm download all the files locally and then sends the changes to the server...